# Unity requires Android SDK to be minimum API level 21

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine

So I've been trying to build a Unity 4.6.1 project in Android, but the problem is that my Android SDK is outdated. However, I believe Google discontinued support of the traditional ADT to switch to Android Studio. Android Studio doesn't have an easy to find SDK folder in version 1.0.1.  This is the error I get: "Error building Player: UnityException: Minimum platform required is Android 5.0 (API level 21)" How do I build my Unity project for Android, if the ADT doesn't have support for API level 21?

Comment: did you set your minimum sdk level in the manifest to an other value than 21?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the SDK manager button (on the top) and in a grayed out text on top of the window (which looks like it did in ADT) it should show you the location of your SDK(e.g. C:\users\admin\appdata...) . And you can change that location in the settings. Just remember to move the files.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

1) Download SDK Tools (v25.2.5) from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

2) Extract in a folder and navigate inside.

3) run `android.bat` which would open `SDK Manager.exe`. **Update the packages from this tool** (must done step). You can also install any specific API if required in your unity project.

4) In Unity, Go to Edit -> Preferences -> External tools and update path for `JDK` and the path of the folder where you extracted SDK Tools.

Now Unity would build for android without any issues.